# Making a function with if statement inside a .val

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Hi I don't know if I'm making this correct. What I'm doing is I'm getting the value of mode of payment and passing it to #editregistrationmodeofpayment.

The code looks like this.

```
$("#editregistrationmodeofpayment").val(response.registration_mode_of_payment);
```

What I want to do, and I'm having a problem in this is if the value of **response.registration_mode_of_payment** is = **'Monthly'** it will load a controller of mine.

What I've done already looks like this.

```
$("#editregistrationmodeofpayment").val(response.registration_mode_of_payment, function(){  
    if($(this).val() == 'Monthly') {
    // Loads the controller
        $("#editmodeofpayment").load('registration/assessModeofPayment/'+schoolyearId+'/'+response.gradelevel_id);
    }
        else { document.getElementById("editmodeofpayment").innerHTML = ""; }
});
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I feel like you should just capture the `.val()` as a variable, and pass that to the function. Then you can parse however you want

Comment: Can you suggest a code of this?

Comment: if response.registration_mode_of_payment holds the value that you want to check if for "monthly" you should write the if statement on response.registration_mode_of_payment

Comment: Where is the `response` coming from? If you can run the function whenever the response changes, you can check `if (response.registration_mode_of_payment) == 'Monthly'` without having to assign the response to the `#editregistrationmodeofpayment` initially.

Comment: @Poku The if statement is already inside the val. I just don't know the right syntax.

Comment: @Owen F the response is coming from my ajax. I'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that response.registration_mode_of_payment is holding the value that you want to do an if statement on. So this should do it:

```
if (response.registration_mode_of_payment === 'monthly') {
    // Loads the controller
$("#editmodeofpayment").load('registration/assessModeofPayment/'+schoolyearId+'/'+response.gradelevel_id);
    }
    else { document.getElementById("editmodeofpayment").innerHTML = ""; }
```